# Access data in external C module from Modelica, in read/overwrite mode

Tags: c, modelica, openmodelica

I'm developing a Modelica library, called "*MyLib*" (in the OpenModelica environment).

I wrote the following external C module ("*ExtTempDataLib.c*"):

```
#ifndef __EXT_LIB_C
#define __EXT_LIB_C

double temperatures [] = {25, 18, 30, 21, 16};

double GetTemperature(int index)
{
    // Modelica indexes start from 1
    return temperatures[index - 1];
}

void SetTemperature(int index, double newTempVal)
{
    // Modelica indexes start from 1
    temperatures[index - 1] = newTempVal;
}

#endif
```

It implements an array of numerical values ("*temperatures*") representing temperatures, which can be read/overwritten via the "*GetTemperature(...)*" and "*SetTemperature(...)*" functions.

The goal is to provide to the Modelica library a set of **global** data (i.e. accessible by all models) that are **not constant**.

Otherwise, I could simply declare the array as a constant inside my "*MyData2*" Modelica package:

```
constant Real temperatures [:] = {25, 18, 30, 21, 16};
```

and then directly access any of its elements (clearly in read-only mode) from any model by simply typing:

```
MyLib.MyData2.temperatures[index];
```

The "*MyData*" Modelica package:

```
within MyLib;
package MyData

model SingleTemperatureOverwrite
    parameter Integer index = 1 "Temperature data index";
    parameter Real newVal = 50 "New temperature value";
algorithm 
    when initial() then
        MyLib.MyData.SetTemperature(index, newVal);
    end when;
end SingleTemperatureOverwrite;


function GetTemperature
    input Integer index;
    output Real temperature;    
    external "C" temperature = GetTemperature(index);
    annotation(Include = "#include \"ExtTempDataLib.c\"");  
end GetTemperature;


function SetTemperature
    input Integer index;
    input Real newTempVal;
    external "C" SetTemperature(index, newTempVal);
    annotation(Include = "#include \"ExtTempDataLib.c\"");
end SetTemperature;

end MyData;
```

defines:

- the "*GetTemperature*" and "*SetTemperature*" functions, which call the corresponding external C functions;
- the "*SingleTemperatureOverwrite*" model, which, at the initial time, overwrites the array value at the specified index with the specified new value (parameters "*index*" and "*newVal*", respectively).

The "*Test*" Modelica package:

```
within MyLib;
package Test

model TemperatureTest
    parameter Integer index = 1 "Temperature data index";
    Real temperature (start = 0) "Temperature value";
equation
    temperature = MyLib.MyData.GetTemperature(index);
end TemperatureTest;

end Test;
```

defines the "*TemperatureTest*" model, which reads the array value at the specified index (the "*index*" parameter) and "copies" it to the "*temperature*" variable.

I created a Modelica test model, including just one instance of "*SingleTemperatureOverwrite*" and one of "*TemperatureTest*" ("*singleTemperatureOverwrite1*" and "*temperatureTest1*", respectively), leaving all parameters at their default value.

The model compiles and executes correctly but, when I plot the "*temperature*" variable of "*temperatureTest1*", instead of getting "50", as I expected, I get "25" (i.e. the starting value of the first element of the array defined in the external C module).

Can somebody please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is no causal link between the two equations so they may execute in an arbitrary order. If you want global, mutable variables in Modelica, I suggest using the inner/outer concept instead of external C. (Or perhaps using external object to enforce execution order)

Comment: I have a few questions:
1) Doesn't _inner/outer_ work just within the same package? (I want the _MyData_ package to provide data accessible from all packages, like e.g. _Test_).
2) Since _SetTemperature_ is done by _SingleTemperatureOverwrite_ at the initial time and _TemperatureTest_'s equation (containing _GetTemperature_) is evaluated at every step, shouldn't it work anyway?
3) What do you exactly mean with "_using external object to enforce execution order_"?

Comment: Using inner/outer works with the entire model. You do need to add an inner object at the appropriate level and all outer instances will refer to the same inner instance (sharing that data). As for external object, it has a constructor which is always called before all other references to the external object. So you can set data in the constructor and access it later.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?
(I've done 1000 tests, but none of them works...)

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you?

```
package GlobalParameter
  model ExampleComponent
    outer parameter Real tValue[5];
  end ExampleComponent;

  model TestT
    ExampleComponent component1;
    ExampleComponent component2;
    inner parameter Real tValue=1:5;
  end TestT;
end GlobalParameter;
```

Comment: No. In your code _TestT_ writes the entire _tValue_ array, while I need the "_TestT_" component to write just one element of the array (at a specified index). Moreover, _TestT_ should not need to "be aware" of the objects composing the "global model" (in your example, the _ExampleComponent_ instances, _component1_ and _component2_).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "TestT should not need to "be aware" of the objects composing the "global model"".  So do you want to do everything at the TestT level?

Comment: I want "_ExampleComponent_" to be a **library** component I can drag and drop in a blank "workspace" in the OpenModelica editor; the same for "_TestT_" (which could be part of a **different** package in the library). I will have up to 5 _TestT_ components in the resulting global model (one for each element of the "_tValue_" array). Therefore, _TestT_ should not declare any _ExampleComponent_ object in its code (_TestT_ should only "know" of (and be able to access) the "global" _tValue_ array (defined by _ExampleComponent_)).

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about this then:

```
package GlobalParameter

  model SetTValue
    outer Real tValue[5];
    parameter Integer index;
    parameter Real value;
  equation 
    tValue[index] = value;
  end SetTValue;

  model TestT
    SetTValue set1(index=1, value=1);
    SetTValue set2(index=2, value=2);
    SetTValue set3(index=3, value=3);
    SetTValue set4(index=4, value=4);
    SetTValue set5(index=5, value=5);

    inner Real tValue[5];
  end TestT;
end GlobalParameter;
```

You do not need to make use of component# (where # is 1-5) but could just use them as a way to set elements of tValue.

A disadvantage of this method is that the SetTValue model is not balanced also to set an index you need to create an instance of SetTValue.  However this approach avoids using external C code.